# Converting JSON to String

Tags: json, android-studio

I am having issues on converting JSON data to readable text. Right now it comes out something like this:

```
{"id":82,"url":"http://www.tvmaze.com/shows/82/game-of-thrones","name":"Game of Thrones","type":"Scripted","language":"English","genres":["Drama","Adventure","Fantasy"],"status":"Running","runtime":60,"premiered":"2011-04-17","schedule":{"time":"21:00","days":["Sunday"]},"rating":{"average":9.3},"weight":10,"network":{"id":8,"name":"HBO","country":{"name":"United States","code":"US","timezone":"America/New_York"}},"webChannel":null,"externals":{"tvrage":24493,"thetvdb":121361,"imdb":"tt0944947"},"image":{"medium":"http://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/medium_portrait/53/132622.jpg","original":"http://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/original_untouched/53/132622.jpg"},"summary":"<p>Based on the bestselling book series <em>A Song of Ice and Fire</em> by George R.R. Martin, this sprawling new HBO drama is set in a world where summers span decades and winters can last a lifetime. From the scheming south and the savage eastern lands, to the frozen north and ancient Wall that protects the realm from the mysterious darkness beyond, the powerful families of the Seven Kingdoms are locked in a battle for the Iron Throne. This is a story of duplicity and treachery, nobility and honor, conquest and triumph. In the <em>\"Game of Thrones\"</em>, you either win or you die.</p>","updated":1485102249,"_links":{"self":{"href":"http://api.tvmaze.com/shows/82"},"previousepisode":{"href":"http://api.tvmaze.com/episodes/729575"},"nextepisode":{"href":"http://api.tvmaze.com/episodes/937256"}}}
```

How would I go about converting this data so I can view it as ID, Name, Genre etc.?

Comment: Paste code question body, and not the whole bunch, but only the snippet that reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to print it to the console, try something like this:

```
    var json = '{"id":82,"url":"http://www.tvmaze.com/shows/82/game-of-thrones","name":"Game of Thrones","type":"Scripted","language":"English","genres":["Drama","Adventure","Fantasy"],"status":"Running","runtime":60,"premiered":"2011-04-17","schedule":{"time":"21:00","days":["Sunday"]},"rating":{"average":9.3},"weight":10,"network":{"id":8,"name":"HBO","country":{"name":"United States","code":"US","timezone":"America/New_York"}},"webChannel":null,"externals":{"tvrage":24493,"thetvdb":121361,"imdb":"tt0944947"},"image":{"medium":"http://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/medium_portrait/53/132622.jpg","original":"http://static.tvmaze.com/uploads/images/original_untouched/53/132622.jpg"},"summary":"<p>Based on the bestselling book series <em>A Song of Ice and Fire</em> by George R.R. Martin, this sprawling new HBO drama is set in a world where summers span decades and winters can last a lifetime. From the scheming south and the savage eastern lands, to the frozen north and ancient Wall that protects the realm from the mysterious darkness beyond, the powerful families of the Seven Kingdoms are locked in a battle for the Iron Throne. This is a story of duplicity and treachery, nobility and honor, conquest and triumph. In the <em>Game of Thrones</em>, you either win or you die.</p>","updated":1485102249,"_links":{"self":{"href":"http://api.tvmaze.com/shows/82"},"previousepisode":{"href":"http://api.tvmaze.com/episodes/729575"},"nextepisode":{"href":"http://api.tvmaze.com/episodes/937256"}}}'

    var  obj = jQuery.parseJSON(json) 

    function printLine(obj){

        for( var i in obj){

            if(typeof obj[i] != 'object') console.log(i + ": " +obj[i]);

            else printLine(obj[i]);
        }
    }

    printLine(obj);
```